# "Suggest an accepted answer" update?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A question about a javascript library called `jQuery`, may once have had an answer suggesting the OP uses `.live()`. Accepted answer, 60 points. At the time, this was correct, but is no longer correct as the feature is now deprecated, yet the question is still valid.

On the same question another answer noted this and added an answer to use `.on()` - which is currently correct.

Is there a way to suggest that the correct answer be changed? Maybe a vote option?

It creates a lot of confusion with older questions as software changes so fast.

I know there's talk of "obsolete answer" vote but this just goes the natural next step.

Comment: Comments are commonly used to suggest changes. Also, you have enough reputation to be able to change answers without having your edit be reviewed. So you could just edit it.

Comment: Ahh, that I didn't know

Comment: @Louis Editing an answer to completely change the approach it uses would be entirely inappropriate.  Adding a note that it has been depreciated since the time that the answer was written would be okay.

Comment: @Servy I never said "completely change the approach".

Comment: @Louis You didn't but it was implied.  Changing the answer from suggesting one thing to suggesting something completely different, when that's the crux of what the answer is about *would* be a radical change to the answer.

Comment: @Servy No, it was not implied either.

Comment: @Louis The OP is saying, "There's a question that suggests using 'foo', but I think it should suggest 'bar'."  You say, "You can edit the post without it being reviewed."  That implies pretty strongly that he should edit the answer to suggest what he thinks it should suggest.  I don't know how you're assuming he would edit the post if not to do that in such a was as to not be a radical edit.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Comment: @Servy: Keeping posts up to date is explicitly on the list of things edits by others are for: ["- To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) Yes, it's a nuisance when people inconsiderately rename parts of their API, but you cannot stop them.

Comment: @Deduplicator And in accordance with that, it would be appropriate to indicate that the method has since been depreciated.  It would not be appropriate to just delete it and write your own new answer.  Also keep in mind not everyone is using the newest version of every product; many people may well be using an older version where the provided answer is the appropriate solution to their problem.

Comment: @servy Excellent point - it's like a balancing act for the information

Answer (score -4):

I want to ask for the same thing. There should be a *"Propose as new accepted answer"* option somewhere (maybe just show the same grey check mark on every answer, but only when hovering that area):

[image: Click to suggest accepting this answer because it solved the problem or was the most helpful in finding a solution (your suggestion will be reviewed; click again to undo)]

This should first pop-up a box and ask for an explanation why the suggestion is made (the edit summary). Once submitted, it should:

- Alert the original asker, who can act on it with immediate effect.
- Enter this as a suggested edit in the review queue. This allows the community to act on it when the original asker is no longer active.
- Allow someone with a good enough rep cutoff (maybe 10,000?) to have the privilege to change the accepted answer without review.

**For now, the workaround appears to be:** If you have enough rep, behold! You can just edit the accepted answer. You can:

- Update the accepted answer entirely.
- Keep the original answer, but add a new section **on top** with an update.
- Keep the original answer, but add a note **at the top** pointing the reader to a different answer with more up-to-date information.

  - **Avoid adding the update on the bottom or somewhere else (like the middle or a comment) because it's not easily visible.** Most readers are interested in the most up-to-date info, so show that first. Leave the outdated info last for the curious.

If you don't have enough rep, you can still do the above edit, but it will enter the suggested edits queue. That means you risk having your edit rejected. Be sure to make your edit good and the summary informative (like saying you're updating outdated info and linking to a current doc).

Comment: ___Don't___ make significant changes to a answer like that. You are not supposed to re-write answers. Notice how I didn't remove your workaround from your answer, even though it's incorrect?

Comment: ***Then*** provide a way to suggest a new accepted answer. There are **genuine** use cases for such a feature. Accepted answers can get outdated over time, and even though another answer could give more current information, a visitor has to plough through the **pinned** accepted (but outdated) answer before getting to the answer with more current info. @Cerbrus

Comment: Standard procedure is to comment on the outdated answer, and post a new updated answer. You _never_ significantly change the contents of an answer. That's not something I decided, that's just how it's worked so far.